# Why do I get "invalid operands types" in one occasion but not in the other, similar one?

Tags: arduino

I have two strings, the first one is concatenated like this:

```
  dataString = String(dates + "," + times + "," + temp[0] + "," + hum[0] + "," +
                      temp[1] + "," + hum[1] + "," + temp[2] + "," + hum[2] +
                      "," + temp[3] + "," + hum[3]);
```

And the other one:

```
dataLog = String("," + airTemp[1] + "," + hum[1] + "," + floorTemp[1]);
```

dates, times are strings; hum, temp, airTemp, and floorTemp are floats.

I've got no problem with the first one, but with the second one, I always get this error message:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char [2]' and 'float' to binary 'operator+'
```

However, if I use `String()` to convert the floats, it works just fine. But then again, I don't have to convert the floats in the first one into strings.

My problem is solved by using String(), but why does this happen?

Comment: In the first case dates is a String.  There are functions to add a String and a float.  In the second case neither one is a String so there’s no function for + to add them.  Using String on small microcontrollers especially overuse of the + operator can lead to heap fragmentation and random crashes.  It’s usually best to avoid it.

Comment: @Delta_G So, it's okay to do String(String + char + float), but not String(char + float)?

Anyway, I just tried `String("," +f)` (where `int f = 1`), and it worked. However, `String("," + f + ",")` didn't work. I am really confused....what's the different between these two?

Comment: I'm not sure why that worked.  The real answer is to stop using the String class.  Where are you sending this String?  If it's going out the Serial line then there's no need to assemble it all into one String.  Just call print with each piece.